# VMware Fusion - Professional Version 8.5.10

Tags: virtualization, vmware, 64-bit

I have a user that has High Sierra (don't ask why) just that he has it, and he is getting an error stating that parts of his VMWare are not 64-bit compatible.

I expect he will need to upgrade to 11, which is almost a given, but here is my question.  If there are instances inside his VM that are 32-Bit compliant only, are they talking about the apps inside his VM? Or are they talking about the VM itself?

I ask this because I went onto the website to look up the information and it's rather sparse. I was hoping the big brains here would be able to help me clear this up a little.

If the message is pertaining to the software inside the VM, I can get one of the techs here to pistolwhip him into submission by actually following protocol.

Otherwise, I'll just tell him to use a VDI as he should be anyway.

Comment: You can run whatever software you want inside a VM. For example, you can run 32 bit apps inside a VM on macOS Catalina. This message must have to do with components of VMware Fusion itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware Fusion 8.x is not supported on macOS 10.13.x High Sierra, he needs version 10.x or newer *(no v9.x exists, because this release was called 8.5.x - and was a free upgrade)*.

You can have a look here: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2088571

It could very well be that High Sierra became more strict about how an app should be built *(no mix between 32-bit and 64-bit ??)* - but still pure 32-bit would be okay, and of course pure 64-bit would also work. But it is only my guess.

Comment: he upgraded to High Sierra... so it may be the reason why it was there in the first place.  In any case, thanks for that link, it makes my life a little easier to resolve my issue. At least by saying "Next time don't update without checking with us first"... 

Thanks again.